# Scroll ListView instead of his Items

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a layout which is divided in other two layouts: a LinearLayout for the "Header" and a RelativeLayout for the "Content".

In the content layout I have a ListView that needs to grown when the user scrolls, and hide this same ListView behind the header layout.
Basically, I need something like this:

[image]

What would be the best aproach to do something like this? This is my layout.xml right now:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_full"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_base"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".app.Main">

    <!-- Header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".55"
        android:background="@drawable/background_header_small"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".45">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_full"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/text_add"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text_add"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text_add"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:showDividers="none"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can I somehow remove the elevator component of the ListView, and scroll the ListView instead of the Items inside the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I can't comment yet.  But you probably want to use the CoordinatorLayout as your parent, instead of the LinearLayout you're using now.  From there you have two options: the hackier way is to use a transparent CollapsingToolbar that is placed underneath the header, the other way is to create your own Behavior that will increase the high/top of the List.

This is under the assumption that the ListView will continue to scroll as normal when the the top of it reaches the top of the screen?

I can throw something together when I get home if this seems like it's on the right track.